# How to create dynamic pages in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to create dynamic pages in Django like in WordPress but I am running out of clue. I have created django blog where data will be updated from admin site and dynamic blog pages will be generated based on postlist, postdetail, and sidebar widget.

Now,

I want to create page where from single view multiple page can be created. For example, About Us page, About Services Page, Contact page, Some Static Page (like privacy policy..)

Where admin will be able to update the content from admin side and decide which content to display on which part of that page. Like ( Image, Video, texts, slides, etc, but that will be independent of template configuration) Like WordPress page customization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to the use-case of About Us/Contact/Policy type pages, i.e pages which change infrequently, Django has the flatpages app. Documentation here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/flatpages/

Flatpages plugs nicely into admin, so you can update them from there.

It also sounds like you want a WYSIWYG editor. For this I would recommend CKEditor. Its highly customisable and there is a well maintained and popular Django integration for it https://pypi.org/project/django-ckeditor/

Its also possible to get CKEditor to work with your flatpages:

admin.py

```
from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.flatpages.admin import FlatPageAdmin
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage

class FlatPageAdmin(FlatPageAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {models.TextField: {"widget": CKEditorWidget}}

# workaround to get the flatpages app to use CKeditor
admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
admin.site.register(FlatPage, FlatPageAdmin)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually what I want is :
Create pages from the admin
edit pages( add extra fields, extra pages sections) I do not mean to add values to just simple prepopulated object from module. 

You can think like how we add extra sections to pages via widget in WordPress. I need to develop WordPress widget like section and WordPress theme settings/update like section. 

So that I will be able to create unlimited pages using structures. You can consider this like a small CMS. I have worked with blog, pages ,categories but  unable to create pages  sections dynamically

Comment: I think you should look into either Wagtail or Django-CMS. They are both built on top of Django and will have a richer set of features which are probably closer to what you require: 

https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/

https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/index.html